# Why my code don't count row in table when using filter checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, count

I have table with checkbox filter, when run code the count run good, but when i checkbox to filter it don't count any, my html:

```
<table class="checkcontainer">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="One" checked="" value="One" onchange="chct()"/> One
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="Two" checked="" value="Two" /> Two
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="Three" checked="" value="Three" /> Three
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="datatbl" border=1 >
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="aaa">
  <tr data-rowtype="One">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>this is first row</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Two">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>this is second row</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Three">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>this is third row</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="One">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>this is fourth row</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Two">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>this is fifth row</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Three">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>this is sixth row</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
window.console.clear();
$('.checkcontainer').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var cbs = $('.checkcontainer').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var all_checked_types = [];
  cbs.each(function() {
    var mycheckbox = $(this);
    $('.datatbl tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('rowtype') == mycheckbox.val();
    }).toggle(mycheckbox[0].checked);
  });
});
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr").length);
function chct() {  
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr").length);
}
```

When i checked checkbox, but function to count row in table not run

How i can count row in table when using filter checkbox ?

Thank you

[Code jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nguoicovan/95t2o4z3/)

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things.  the filter doesn't destroy the tr element.  the jquery :visible and :hidden filters are going to count based on the display attribute.  and you have to recalculate the count field value within the onchange handler.  jsfiddle updated.

```
window.console.clear();
$('.checkcontainer').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var cbs = $('.checkcontainer').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var all_checked_types = [];
  cbs.each(function() {
    var mycheckbox = $(this);
    $('.datatbl tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('rowtype') == mycheckbox.val();
    }).toggle(mycheckbox[0].checked);
  });
});
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr").length);
function chct() {  
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr").length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here :

1. You don't call your `chct` function when the filter changed.
2. Your selector just get the number of `tr`, even if they're not visible. Just add `:visible` to it.

```js
window.console.clear();
$('.checkcontainer').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var cbs = $('.checkcontainer').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var all_checked_types = [];
  cbs.each(function() {
    var mycheckbox = $(this);
    $('.datatbl tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('rowtype') == mycheckbox.val();
    }).toggle(mycheckbox[0].checked);
  });
  chct();
});
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr").length);
function chct() {  
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr:visible").length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="checkcontainer">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="One" checked="" value="One" onchange="chct()"/> One
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="Two" checked="" value="Two" /> Two
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='filter' id="Three" checked="" value="Three" /> Three
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="datatbl" border=1 >
  <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="aaa">
  <tr data-rowtype="One">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>this is first row</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Two">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>this is second row</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Three">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>this is third row</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="One">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>this is fourth row</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Two">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>this is fifth row</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-rowtype="Three">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>this is sixth row</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="total">
  empty
</div>
```

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use :Visible (this counts visible tr in that table)

```
window.console.clear();
$('.checkcontainer').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

  var cbs = $('.checkcontainer').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var all_checked_types = [];
  cbs.each(function() {
    var mycheckbox = $(this);
    $('.datatbl tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('rowtype') == mycheckbox.val();
    }).toggle(mycheckbox[0].checked);
  });

  chct();
});

function chct() {  
$("#total").text($("#aaa tr:visible").length);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/95t2o4z3/5/)